# Pip failing to install dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I have an open source project (GridCal) and I tell users to install the package with `pip install GridCal` or `pip3 install GridCal` for unix systems.

The setup file is this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import sys
import os
import platform
from GridCal.grid.CalculationEngine import __GridCal_VERSION__

name = "GridCal"
version = str(__GridCal_VERSION__)
description = "Research Oriented electrical simulation software."

# Python 3.5 or later needed
if sys.version_info < (3, 5, 0, 'final', 0):
    raise (SystemExit, 'Python 3.5 or later is required!')

# Build a list of all project modules
packages = []
for dir_name, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(name):
        if '__init__.py' in file_names:
            packages.append(dir_name.replace('/', '.'))

package_dir = {name: name}

# Data_files (e.g. doc) needs (directory, files-in-this-directory) tuples
data_files = []
for dir_name, dir_names, file_names in os.walk('doc'):
        files_list = []
        for filename in file_names:
            fullname = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
            files_list.append(fullname)
        data_files.append(('share/' + name + '/' + dir_name, files_list))

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    # list the packages (On windows anaconda is assumed)
    required_packages = ["numpy",
                         "scipy",
                         "networkx",
                         "pandas",
                         "xlwt",
                         "xlrd",
                         # "PyQt5",
                         "matplotlib",
                         "qtconsole",
                         "pysot",
                         "openpyxl",
                         "pulp"
                         ]
else:
    # make the desktop entry
    make_linux_desktop_file(version_=version, comment=description)

    # list the packages
    required_packages = ["numpy",
                         "scipy",
                         "networkx",
                         "pandas",
                         "xlwt",
                         "xlrd",
                         "PyQt5",
                         "matplotlib",
                         "qtconsole",
                         "pysot",
                         "openpyxl",
                         "pulp"
                         ]

# Read the license
with open('LICENSE.txt', 'r') as f:
    license_text = f.read()

setup(
    # Application name:
    name=name,

    # Version number (initial):
    version=version,

    # Application author details:
    author="Santiago Peñate Vera",
    author_email="santiago.penate.vera@gmail.com",

    # Packages
    packages=packages,

    data_files=data_files,

    # Include additional files into the package
    include_package_data=True,

    # Details
    url="http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GridCal/",

    # License file
    license=license_text,

    # description
    description=description,

    # long_description=open("README.txt").read(),

    # Dependent packages (distributions)
    install_requires=required_packages,

    setup_requires=required_packages
)
```

From time to time I get users reports saying that the program is missing modules: https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/issues/12

I have specified the list of packages both in `install_requires` and `setup_requires`.

Is this a pip bug, or shall I do something else?

Comment: I don't see `pyDOE` in the list of dependencies. How is it installed? Is it a dependenciy of a listed dependency?

Comment: I doubt you need both `install_requires` and `setup_requires` at the same time. Also see the warning at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=setup_requires#installation-bundles: *Finally, beware of the setup_requires keyword arg in setup.py. The (rare) packages that use it will cause those dependencies to be downloaded by setuptools directly, skipping pip's protections.*

Comment: pyDOE is installed with pySOT, and BTW this setup works perfectly in linux,  and sometimes not so well in windows. Hence the question.

Comment: Your [setup.py](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/UnderDevelopment/setup.py#L5) imports `GridCal.grid.CalculationEngine` which imports almost all of your dependencies. I.e. your `setup.py` imports  dependencies **before** installing them. How does that supposed to work? Try to install it in a new empty virtual env — that surely doesn't work. I got *ImportError: No module named 'numpy'*.

Comment: Also it doesn't work with Python 2:  `def classify_by_hour(t: pd.DatetimeIndex):`
                              ^
    *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

Comment: python 2 is not supported (and it is being dropped by 2020), and from the engine it only imports the version: `from GridCal.Engine.CalculationEngine import __GridCal_VERSION__` therefore your assumption is wrong. Furthermore, I do have a video with a clear windows 10 where the setup works. The video is in the github repository for your reference. Now the question is still valid, why does it fail sometimes?

Comment: If python 2 is not supported you'd better not teach people to use `pip install`, only document `pip3 install`. When you do `from GridCal.Engine.CalculationEngine import` the entire module is imported, hence the import error. I really recommend you to try installing in an empty virtual env, you'll see the problem immediately: it doesn't fail *sometimes*, it fails **always**.

Comment: stack overflow is to solve people's issues, so if you don't know don't answer

Comment: I surely know. You can know it too. Please take a little break and do an experiment with a new empty virtual env detached from your global `site-packages` (`virtualenv --no-site-packages`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup.py` imports `GridCal.grid.CalculationEngine` which imports almost all of your dependencies. I.e. your `setup.py` imports dependencies **before** installing them.

Try to install it in a new empty virtual env detached from your global `site-packages` — that surely doesn't work:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages --python python3.4 test-gcal
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/phd/tmp/test-gcal/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in /home/phd/tmp/test-gcal/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

$ source test-gcal/bin/activate

$ pip install GridCal
Collecting GridCal
  Using cached GridCal-1.85.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c7q9pbep/GridCal/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        from GridCal.grid.CalculationEngine import __GridCal_VERSION__
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c7q9pbep/GridCal/GridCal/grid/CalculationEngine.py", line 18, in <module>
        from GridCal.grid.JacobianBased import IwamotoNR, Jacobian, LevenbergMarquardtPF
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c7q9pbep/GridCal/GridCal/grid/JacobianBased.py", line 19, in <module>
        from numpy import array, angle, exp, linalg, r_, Inf, conj, diag, asmatrix, asarray, zeros_like, zeros, complex128, \
    ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-c7q9pbep/GridCal/
```

The fix is relatively straightforward: you have to move `__GridCal_VERSION__` from `GridCal/Engine/CalculationEngine.py` to a separate `GridCal/version.py` (or `__version__.py` or something like this) and do `from GridCal.version import __GridCal_VERSION__` in `setup.py`.

Please remember that import would work only if your `GridCal/__init__.py` is empty or only imports builtin/standard modules. If said `__init__.py` directly or indirectly imports a (not yet installed) dependency `version.py` could not be imported. There is a way to overcome this in `setup.py` but I skip it for now. If your ever will need the solution — ask again.